# Why abstract variable null does not equal to null

Tags: java, null

I've programmed for quite a time, but I never got to this. I deploy on JRE 1.8.0_66.
I wrote an abstract class called `Grenade`. Then I made these statements in class `Profile`:

```
public class Profile {
    Grenade varGrenade; // Field
    public void check() {
        varGrenade = null; // set reference to null
        System.out.println("Am i null: " + this.varGrenade == null);
    }
}
```

This statement returns

> Am i null: false

If I would want to print the result of `varGreanade`, it would print `null`. Where have I gone wrong? (Don't know if it has something with abstract Grenade class) How do I check it for `null` without throwing `NullPointerException`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just an issue of parentheses.  What you want is

```
System.out.println("Am i null: " + (this.varGrenade == null));
```

What you're getting is

```
System.out.println(("Am i null: " + this.varGrenade) == null);
```

Answer (score 1):

`"Am i null: " + this.varGrenade` is not null.

You need parentheses to force it to concatenate to the null-check.

(just like `1 + 2 == 3` doesn't mean `1 + (2 == 3)`)